# podman login fails with invalid credentials to docker.io

Tags: podman

Trying this command

```
podman login -u xxx@xxx.com -p XXX@XXX_XXXXX -v docker.io                                                                                                                                                
Error: error logging into "docker.io": invalid username/password
```

The same credentials work with logging into docker hub.

podman version used is `4.0.3`.

I am running on an MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) Apple M1 Max.

Comment: "*... between the both ...*" - between which both? `docker` and `podman`?

Comment: If the error says that the creds don't work, then it's worth trying a different set of creds that you know work . Then if _those_ don't work you know the problem is in the command not the creds.

Comment: yes I can log into docker hub with credentials and they work, then try the same credentials in the podman command line and they don't work.

Comment: Can you try `podman login docker.io` and input the credentials manually?

Comment: I did try that as well, also i changed password so it only has letters, numbers, dashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using my email as the username, which was not correct.  I needed to use my "username".  But since the portal allows me to login with my email, I thought that was my 'username'.

Comment: Happened to me a few years ago, happened again today. I think it would be nice if podman would warn if there is an @ in the user name, wouldn't it?